# How to make Simplify[] work with substitutions?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

There is a matrix $M$, and as far as it has quite a complicated form, there are several algebraic equations defining some of its parameters. I try to find the inverse of $M$ and simplify it. Unfortunately, $Mathematica$ gives the answer in the form, differing from the one I want: precisely, it substitutes parameters in the inverse matrix instead of giving the answer in terms of parameters (where it is possible).

Concretely, I have
$$\rho = \sqrt{r^2 + a^2 Cos[\Theta]^2}$$
$$\Delta = r^2 - 2 m r + a^2 + e^2$$
and want the answer to be given in terms of $\Delta$ and $\rho$, where it is possible.

I tried to use $\mathsf{Eliminate[]}$ instead of $\mathsf{FullSimplify[]}$, but did not succeed. Moreover, there is a problem with $\mathsf{Eliminate[]}$: there may be no possibility to fully eliminate the parameters.

Is there any way to make $Mathematica$ work as I want?

#### EDIT:

I have following problem:

```
\[Rho] = Sqrt[r^2 + a^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2];

\[CapitalDelta] = r^2 - 2 m r + a^2 + e^2;

Metric = {{\[Rho]^2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, - a Sin[\[Theta]]^2, 
1}, {0, - 
  a Sin[\[Theta]]^2, \[Rho]^-2 ((r^2 + 
     a^2)^2 - \[CapitalDelta] a^2  Sin[\[Theta]]^2) \
Sin[\[Theta]]^2, - a \[Rho]^-2 (2 m r - e^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2}, {0, 
1, - a \[Rho]^-2 (2 m r - 
   e^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2, -(1 - \[Rho]^-2 (2 m r - e^2))}};

InvMetric = Inverse[Metric] // Simplify // MatrixForm
```

And what I get is:

[image: this],

although I want to get $\rho^{-2}$ instead of (0; 0) entry, for example.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I included my problem in the question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I am sorry for my mistake: I decided to rename it before sending here. Kerr = Metric. I will edit the question.

Comment: What is your definition of "simplified"?  If you mean eliminating two of `{a, e, m, r, θ}` in terms of `{Δ, ρ}`, doing so is fairly straightforward but you may not be happy with what you get.  Simplification is one of the hardest things to accomplish with symbolic algebra programs, in part because there is no clear definition of what it means, and everyone   means something different.  Mathematic attempts to minimize `LeafCount`.  By the way, I do not get what you have in the question for ` InvKerr`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, my definition is the one you mention. I was not aware about the mechanism of simplifying. So you suggest doing such things by hand?

Comment: If by your last comment  you mean eliminating two of `{a, e, m, r, θ}` which two?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Actually, `{m, e}` as far as they are together everywhere shall be changed for $\Delta$ and I also would like to use $\rho$ for the combinations like `r^2 + a^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2`, although it is impossible to get rid of `r, a and Theta` at once. 
I see even better what you mean by difficulty of simplification procedure now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for your example:

```
Simplify[
    InvMetric,
    Cos[2 θ]==2Cos[θ]^2-1 && ρ^2==r^2+a^2 Cos[θ]^2 && Δ==r^2-2 m r+a^2+e^2
] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \frac{1}{\rho ^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & \frac{\Delta }{\rho ^2} & \frac{a}{\rho ^2} & \frac{a^2+r^2}{\rho ^2} \\
>  0 & \frac{a}{\rho ^2} & \frac{\csc ^2(\theta )}{\rho ^2} & \frac{a}{\rho ^2} \\
>  0 & \frac{a^2+r^2}{\rho ^2} & \frac{a}{\rho ^2} & \frac{a^2 \sin ^2(\theta )}{\rho ^2}
>    \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$